# Best way to run same function many times in IntentService

Tags: android, kotlin, background, intentservice

My app performs quite simple task - it collects cellInfo, extracts cid number of cell tower and put it in main activity when there's a text view with some kind of log of cell ids. Each cellid collects one time per 2 seconds. This function is stored in Intent Service and also there is a notification that appears every time user starts logging.

Recently I found out that despite the fact that there is a `Thread.sleep(1000L)` in do-while loop, some smartphones do not keep service working correctly. I.e. when I turn off screen, an Intent Service stops working however notification is still present. Sometimes I noticed that some phones run function of getting cellids much slower ignoring sleep method. But when I launch an app with charger plugged in everything works fine on every phone. Not sure it is all about charging but I need delay to be the same on multiple phones.

Here is what I tried.

**Works at different speeds on different phones**

```
fun counter(bc: Intent){
    val tm = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    var quit = 0
    var i = 0
    do {
        i += 1
        quit = Trigger.getTrigger() // companion object 
        val num_cid = getcids(tm) // function that takes cell tower cid (int)
        bc.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, num_cid .toString()) // sending cid to broadcastIntent
        sendBroadcast(bc) 
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    while (quit == 0)
}
```

**Works better but notification does not appear.**

```
fun counter(bc: Intent){
    val tm = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    Handler().postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (Trigger.getTrigger() == 0) {
                i += 1
                val num_cid = getcids(tm)
                bc.putExtra(CURRENT_CID, num_cid .toString())
                sendBroadcast(bc)
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        }
    }, 0)
}
```

What should be done here to have same speeds on every phone and notification presented?

Comment: can you share your `IntentService` code?

Answer (score 0):

So, in recent system updates Google especially made restriction on background [services](https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/background-services-in-android-o-a38a7c624391). System will eventually kill your app, if it only runs background service. To overcome this limitations foreground [services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) or [Job Scheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) are used.